# How to rotate a large background image once the next image loads, but without having to preload all at once?

Tags: jquery, rotation, background-image, cycle, preloader

I need a large rotating background image on a homepage. This is how I want it to work:

During the first round, the next image is displayed only after it is preloaded. While it's waiting on the current image, there should be a small spinner overlaid in the corner. Once it cycles through each and consequently they all have been loaded, it will default to a regular interval.

I don't want to have to preload all the images and then cycle through, but I also don't want to just cycle through and have one disappear and a gap until the next loads.

I've been looking around for jQuery plugins that cycle background images and preload only the next image at a time. So far I've just found plugins that only rotate or only preload. Does what I want exist? If so, where can I find it? Otherwise, do I have to find a way to merge the two myself? Any tips for doing that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you out:

[Advanced jQuery background image slideshow](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/advanced_jquery_background_image_slideshow.html)

Good luck, please tell me if that was what you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I have an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/27UHX/

It preloads each image, calling the next preload after it is done.  After the last one, it begins rotating through each image normally.

It's mostly plain JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks.  It is generally good practice to accept the answer in that case. :)  Just click the check mark next to this answer.